# Can I perform conditional inserts inside DB transaction try...catch block?

Tags: laravel

I need to perform 3 DB inserts inside a transaction, but 1 of them is optional, depending on an input value. Is it OK to only insert into the 3rd table if the condition is met and keep everything in the same transaction? Or I will need to do it outside and verify integrity later?

Example:

```
try {
    DB::beginTransaction();    

    $insertId = DB::table('table1')->insertGetId([
       // ...
    ]);

    DB::table('table2')->insert([
       // ...
    ]);

    // Conditional insert:
    if ($request->flag) {
        DB::table('table3')->insert([
           // ...
        ]);
    }    

    DB::commit();

} catch (\Exception $e) {
    DB::rollback();   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to rollback all of them when the `table3` insert operation fails? If yes, you can use it in the same transaction.

If you don't want to rollback but ensure the `table3` operation is complete, you can use Laravel's Queue system. With the queue system:

1. You can monitor failed jobs on the "failed_jobs" SQL table.
2. You can send slack/email notifications to yourself about failed jobs.
3. On failure, the `table3` insert operation can automatically run multiple times at different hours to bypass short-time problems like HTTP timeout, DB connection, etc.
4. On failure, you can modify the job and retry it by using `php artisan queue:retry {{failed-job-uuid}}` command

Documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queues